# How to change the header font size and remove the footer in Jekyll minima theme?

Tags: css, sass, jekyll, minima

I would like to use Jekyll's minima theme but would like to:

1. Increase the size of the header (it will occupy a somewhat bigger fraction of the screen). I would also like to remove the line that separates the header from the rest.
2. Remove the footer

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Use a file `assets/main.scss` with the following content:

```
---
---

@import "{{ site.theme }}";
.site-title {font-size: 50px;}
.site-header {border: none;}
.site-footer {display: none;}
```